# TensorFlow 2.0 and NetCDF4 RuntimeError: HDF error - Possible issue with I/O

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, hdf5, netcdf4

While trying to write a NumPy array of floats to a NetCDF4 dataset, I am getting a `RuntimeError: NetCDF: HDF error`. I believe that somewhere TensorFlow2.0 is messing up with NetCDF4, but I do need to import both in the same class/function. It is not clear why the sequence of importing libraries is affecting I/O of a NetCDF4 file.
Here's a sample script:

```py
##The sequence of import which doesn't work
import numpy as np  
import tensorflow as tf       ### <<< if imported here, saving .nc doesn't work
import netCDF4 as nc
#import tensorflow as tf      ### <<< if imported here, saving .nc works properly

print("I am TensorFlow ", tf.__version__, " but I have no job here")
print("I would let NetCDF4 ", nc.__version__," do it's job, for now")

Nx = 160                            # just another number
outputfile = "outputfile.nc"        # just another filename
ArrayField = np.ones((Nx,Nx,1))     # sample array to write

print("Writing field data of shape", ArrayField.shape)
ncfile = nc.Dataset("outputfile.nc",'w',format='NETCDF4_CLASSIC')

ncfile.createDimension('X',ArrayField.shape[0])             #line is probably okay
newx = ncfile.createVariable('X','d',('X'))                 #line is probably okay
newx[:] = np.linspace(0.00,1.00,ArrayField.shape[0])        #line is probably okay
velx = ncfile.createVariable('Component_X','d',('X','X'))   #line is probably okay
velx[:] = ArrayField[:,:,0].T                               #line is probably okay

print("Something written to: ", outputfile)
ncfile.close()  ###### <<<<<<< Gives error here 
print("Data successfully written to: ", outputfile)
```

Output/Error:

```py
I am TensorFlow  2.0.0  but I have no job here
I would let NetCDF4  1.5.3  do it's job, for now
Writing field data of shape (160, 160, 1)
Something written to:  outputfile.nc
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-1cfdf4070b97> in <module>
     22 
     23 print("Something written to: ", outputfile)
---> 24 ncfile.close()  ###### <<<<<<< Gives error here
     25 print("Data successfully written to: ", outputfile)
netCDF4/_netCDF4.pyx in netCDF4._netCDF4.Dataset.close()
netCDF4/_netCDF4.pyx in netCDF4._netCDF4.Dataset._close()
netCDF4/_netCDF4.pyx in netCDF4._netCDF4._ensure_nc_success()
RuntimeError: NetCDF: HDF error
```

Expected Output:

```py
I am TensorFlow  2.0.0  but I have no job here
I would let NetCDF4  1.5.3  do it's job, for now
Writing field data of shape (160, 160, 1)
Something written to:  outputfile.nc
Data successfully written to:  outputfile.nc
```

Though I can import TF2.0 after importing NetCDF4 for this particular sample to work, it doesn't really answer the question about getting a `RuntimeError: NetCDF: HDF error` and fixing the issue for its use in complex cases. Also, I would like to return more debugging information.

1. Tested with `tensorflow==2.1.0` and `2.2.0`, gives the same error.
2. Disk size of created garbage .nc file is `~204K` which should be about `~209K` for this array sample.
3. Issue persists on a different machine or a clean environment by installing only `tensorflow==2.0.0`, `numpy==1.17.3`, `netCDF4==1.5.3`.
4. Just in case, here's a `pip freeze` list of my clean environment: https://gist.github.com/aakash30jan/9ae0cf3dde8a63d28df5275873cb0f10